# Name of functions that are similar to atan2

Tags: trigonometry

There was a grouping I saw once of functions that are similar to atan2 where the Y result can only ever be below 1 and over -1 and the closer the value is to the maximum or minimum the longer it takes to reach it on the X axis (until infinity).

Does anyone know the name of these functions?

[image: atan2]

Comment: sigmoids, probably.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such functions are called sigmoid.
Differentiable everywhere with non-negative derivative, bounded.

Comment: This is exactly it, thank you!

Comment: Since "sigmoid" means "S-shaped", you probably also want a require a sigmoid function to be convex at first and then change to concave (exactly once, not back and forth between convex and concave).